# How to Get Reminder Status in Docusign Connect .NetApi

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

Team Docusign,
I want to capture history of all Docusign Envelopes Status . I am able to capture them too, but fight is with Reminders,
I want to save reminder status for history tracking in another system using MSSQL.

How can I get the status of reminder when it reminds users whether this Envelope has sent reminder or not and date as well..
For e.g. First reminder is set for 7 days and second one after 21 days. In this case , how do I capture this reminder sending event using Docusign Connect with .Net.
I am able to capture all Envelope Statues but not reminders.

Answer (score 0):

Reminders are not official envelope events which is why DocuSign Connect probably does not include them.  Have you tried checking the audit history of the envelopes in question?

To retrieve an envelopes audit events you can make the following request:

[Envelopes: listAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/)

Comment: Will try it and get back soon.

Comment: Hey Ergin,I tried AuditEventList, but there is no status which matches with Reminders, even though it sent reminder, but status was not showing in History. I can try something  like, I will capture document sent date + Calculate First Reminder Date from Document Sent Date, for e.g. Document is sent on 01 Oct and first reminder is set for 7 Days, so I will calculate number of days of first reminder 08 October,  and if same envelopeid is used for sent again...will save it in databse...it is just thought, but not sure will it work or not.